# Python: get string representation of PyObject?

Tags: python, string, pyobject

I've got a C python extension, and I would like to print out some diagnostics.

I'm receiving a string as a `PyObject*`.

What's the canonical way to obtain a string representation of this object, such that it usable as a `const char *`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `PyObject_Repr` (to mimic Python's `repr` function) or `PyObject_Str` (to mimic `str`), and then  call `PyString_AsString` to get `char *` (you can, and usually should, use it as `const char*`, for example:

```
PyObject* objectsRepresentation = PyObject_Repr(yourObject);
const char* s = PyString_AsString(objectsRepresentation);
```

This method is OK for any `PyObject`. If you are absolutely sure `yourObject` is a Python string and not something else, like for instance a number, you can skip the first line and just do:

```
const char* s = PyString_AsString(yourObject);
```

Comment: I am trying PyBytes_AsString(yourObject) for Python 3 and I am getting TypeError: expected bytes, str found

Comment: I didn't even mention PyBytes_AsString in my answer. Have you tried what I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I tried, in Py3.x PyString got replaced with PyBytes but with not quite the same functionality.  I ended up using:  PyUnicode_AsUTF8(objectsRepresentation)

Comment: Don't forget to `Py_DECREF(objectsRepresentation)` since `PyObject_Repr()` returns a new reference!

Answer (score 43):

Here is the correct answer if you are using Python 3:

```
static void reprint(PyObject *obj) {
    PyObject* repr = PyObject_Repr(obj);
    PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(repr, "utf-8", "~E~");
    const char *bytes = PyBytes_AS_STRING(str);

    printf("REPR: %s\n", bytes);

    Py_XDECREF(repr);
    Py_XDECREF(str);
}
```

Comment: And what if my `PyObject` is plain python string, how can I convert it to `const char*`?

Comment: Please note that `PyObject_Repr` places single quotes around your string.

Comment: @Montreal Same as the example above, but omit `PyObject_Repr`. For safety you may use `if(!PyUnicode_CheckExact(obj)){...}` to verify that `PyObject *obj` is indeed a `PyUnicode_Type`.

Comment: What does `"~E~"` mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1 in this example, this will replace invalid characters/data with the string `"~E~"`

Comment: single quotes in result string...

Answer (score 13):

If you need just print the object in Python 3 you can use one of these functions:

```
static void print_str(PyObject *o)
{
    PyObject_Print(o, stdout, Py_PRINT_RAW);
}

static void print_repr(PyObject *o)
{
    PyObject_Print(o, stdout, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `PyObject_Repr` (to mimic Python's `repr`) or `PyObject_Str` (to mimic Python's `str`).

Docs:

> Compute a string representation of
>   object o. Returns the string
>   representation on success, NULL on
>   failure. This is the equivalent of the
>   Python expression repr(o). Called by
>   the repr() built-in function.

Comment: this looks like what I need... Once I've got the PyObject returned by one of these functions, how do I access that in a C-friendly way (eg. to call printf, etc)

Answer (score 2):

For python >=3.3:

```
char* str = PyUnicode_1BYTE_DATA(py_object);
```

Yes, this is a non-const pointer, you can potentially modify the (immutable) string via it.

Comment: python 3.10:
error: invalid conversion from ‘Py_UCS1*’ {aka ‘unsigned char*’} to ‘char*’

Answer (score 1):

PyObject *module_name;
PyUnicode_AsUTF8(module_name)

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary `PyObject*`, first call
[`PyObject_Repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Repr) or [`PyObject_Str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str) to get a `PyUnicode*` object.

In Python 3.3 and up, call [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize). In addition to the Python string you want a `const char *` for, this function takes an optional address to store the length in.

Python strings are objects with explicit length fields that may contain null bytes, while a `const char*` by itself is typically a pointer to a null-terminated C string. Converting a Python string to a C string is a potentially lossy operation. For that reason, all the other Python C-API functions that could return a `const char*` from a string are [deprecated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9abd07e5963f966c4d6df8f4e4bf390ed8191066/Include/cpython/unicodeobject.h#L729-L742).

If you do not care about losing a bunch of the string if it happens to contain an embedded null byte, you can pass `NULL` for the `size` argument. For example,

```
PyObject* foo = PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize("foo\0bar", 7);

printf("As const char*, ignoring length: %s\n",
    PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(foo, NULL));
```

prints

```
As const char*, ignoring length: foo
```

But you can also pass in the address of a `size` variable, to use with the `const char*`, to make sure that you’re getting the entire string.

```
PyObject* foo = PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize("foo\0bar", 7);

printf("Including size: ");
size_t size;
const char* data = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(foo, &size);
fwrite(data, sizeof(data[0]), size, stdout);
putchar('\n');
```

On my terminal, that outputs

```
$ ./main | cat -v
Including size: foo^@bar
```