# How do I get string representation of PyObject in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I am debugging Python source code (CPython 3.4). I'm receiving a PyObject*. I would like to `printf` it.

For example (from Objects/floatobject.c of Python 3.4 source code):

```
PyObject *o_ndigits = NULL;
Py_ssize_t ndigits;

x = PyFloat_AsDouble(v);
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|O", &o_ndigits))
    return NULL;
```

How do I `printf` o_ndigits? It is almost same as this question: [Python: get string representation of PyObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356773/python-get-string-representation-of-pyobject), but for Python3. With original solution, I got `"undefined reference to PyString_AsString"` error.

Answer (score 4):

Both `PyObject_Repr` and `PyObject_ASCII` return a unicode `str` representation of the object. If your terminal doesn't use UTF-8, you probably want the ASCII escaped representation. Get the multibyte string with `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` or [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize`](http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize). The new implementation in 3.3 caches the UTF-8 byte string, so don't deallocate it after printing.

As to `PyString_AsString`, that became `PyBytes_AsString` or `PyBytes_AS_STRING` for the 3.x `bytes` type.