# How does Python's repr work on classes and instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr

I'm curious how `repr` works. It can't be exactly

```
def repr_(x):
  return x.__repr__()
```

since that does not work on classes, namely

```
repr_(int)
```

causes an error since `int`'s repr expects an `int` object as the first argument. I know that I can customize a class's `repr` by creating a metaclass with a desired `__repr__`, but I want to know how does Python's built in `repr` work? And **how does it specifically handle the case of having a class passed into it.**

Does it do something like a try catch where it first tries what my `repr_` does and then looks up the MRO for other reprs? Or something else?

Comment: Try `repr_(3)` instead of the type `int` which is _not_ an instance.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but `help(repr)` says this: `For many object types, including most builtins, eval(repr(obj)) == obj.`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If we inspect how Python internally computes `repr`, which we can see in the source file [object.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L506-L551), we can see that repr is essentially

```
def repr_(x):
  return x.__class__.__repr__(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

import datetime

today=datetime.date.today()

print(repr(today))

for objects of classes, repr basically displays unambiguous output when obj call is their.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2015/docs/python-3.4.2-docs-html/library/functions.html#repr

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.
>   For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
>   would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval(),
>   otherwise the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets
>   that contains the name of the type of the object together with
>   additional information often including the name and address of the
>   object. A class can control what this function returns for its
>   instances by defining a **repr**() method.

Comment: I understand what `repr` means, and what it's supposed to do. I understand how to customize `repr` for custom classes using a custom metaclass. I want to know how Python **internally** decides what `__repr__` to call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356773/python-get-string-representation-of-pyobject Check this out, this might help you.